# Why is Perl pos() always returning undef?

Tags: perl

Perl v5.26.3

I don't understand why this isn't working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $var = "one two three four";
$var =~ m/three/i;
print $var . "\n";
print Dumper(pos($var));
print Dumper(@-);
print Dumper(@+);
```

I can't figure out why `pos` always returns `undef` no matter what i try. Shouldn't it be the same as `@+` in this case?

```
# Output from code
one two three four
$VAR1 = undef;
$VAR1 = 8;
$VAR1 = 13;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation of pos](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos):

> Returns the offset of where the last m//g search left off ...

There is no `m//g` in your code. There is only `m//`, without the `/g` modifier. Once added, `pos` returns the expected value.